# How to pass SSL cert and key from jenkins keystore to file and use it in nginx configuration

Tags: docker, nginx, ssl, jenkins

My dream is to pass SSL cert files to nginx from jenkins "**Certificate - a PKCS#12 certificate file**", acc. to this doc: https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/using/using-credentials/?fbclid=IwAR0bo4ubrvhN-6TX99SYn-OLN4KnM2UewQuPkczyQSFo4xQp0B8iJAm_Wks I should create a keystore with my crt and key, and throw it to jenkins.

I can't find any article describing the full path from this storage to nginx setup. My current docker for nginx setup looks like below:

```
FROM nginx:1.17.5-alpine
COPY example.com.crt /etc/nginx/ssl/example.com.crt
COPY example.com.key /etc/nginx/ssl/example.com.key
```

How to bring the crt and key from jenkins to the files form, so I could copy them to nginx?

Thanks for help, please excuse me if this is a duplicate as I failed to find such description.

Comment: My suggestion would be to use base64 encoding and decoding. You can save your crt and key in jenkins creds, then use echo to write them to a file in the jenkins workspace and copy them to nginx container

Comment: I tried to do this, but have a problem when i try to move the crts from creds to files like below:
```
sh "printf '%s' '${SSL_CRT_PSW}' > example.com.crt"

```
I'm getting: failed (SSL: error:0909006C:PEM routines:get_name:no start line:Expecting: TRUSTED CERTIFICATE)

Comment: what's the problem? I have done this in past in jenkins and gitlab

Comment: Please see my edited message, I was able to find that this nginx err is related to file encoding, but was not able to find how to improve this.

Comment: OK, thanks for the base64 snippet, I was able to resolve this issue with this, and the nginx err was related to multipleline base64 generation, AND IT NEEDS TO BE IN SINGLE LINE.

Comment: I will update the OP with the solution. Please accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best solution would be to use base64 encoding decoding. We encode the crt and key with base64 and save as jenkins creds.

The creds are then directed to a file using simple shell command.